# How to dis-align children of adjacent table-cells?

Tags: css, alignment, text-alignment

My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jacky_lei/de8ntgsn/) has a `div` with `display:table` with 2 children with `display:table-cell`. The children each have different padding 
but the content inside each of them are still aligned. Is there a way around this? I want `child-two` to stay aligned with the top left corner of the table-cell without using position relative/absolute. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align`:

```
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  vertical-align: top;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS:

```
.table-cell:nth-of-type(2) {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hpfye47v/1/